# Add Field Codes to INCLUDEIMAGE field

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-field

We need to set the "Data not stored with document" flag ("\d") when adding a Field to an existing Word document via Interop but can't figure how to do so.

This example works well in terms of inserting the image link but it stores the image within the document and not remotely (which we need).

```
            if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("TrackingPixel"))
            {
                object oBookMark = "TrackingPixel";
                object newText = @"https://www.remotelocation.com/trackingpixel/secretcode";

                Range rng = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range;
                rng.Select();

                rng.Fields.Add(
                    Range: rng,
                    Type: WdFieldType.wdFieldIncludePicture,
                    Text: newText,
                    PreserveFormatting: true
                    );

            }
```

Any held would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways adding switches to field codes can be done.

In the case presented in the question, the switch can be added to the string passed to the `Text`parameter:

```
    if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("TrackingPixel"))
    {
        string fieldSwitches = " \d";
        object oBookMark = "TrackingPixel";
        object newText = @"https://www.remotelocation.com/trackingpixel/secretcode" + fieldSwitches;

        Range rng = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range;
        // There's usually no need to select the Range unless the user should work with it
        //rng.Select();

        rng.Fields.Add(
            Range: rng,
            Type: WdFieldType.wdFieldIncludePicture,
            Text: newText,
            PreserveFormatting: true
            );
    }
```

If this were an existing field code (the switch should be added after the fact) it's possible to assign new content to the string. For example:

```
string fldCode = field.Code.Text;
fldCode += " \d";
field.Code.Text = fldCode;
field.Update();
```

FWIW when adding a field I often pass the entire field code in as a string (use only the `Text` parameter) and leave out the `Type` parameter. I'll also set `PreserveFormatting` to `false` unless I know I explicitly want that behavior. The first is a personal preference. For the second, the `\* MergeFormat` switch can result in very odd behavior when a field code updates with other (formatted, string) content. I will use it, however, for linked tables.

Comment: Perfect - thank you for your help!  I had already tried the first option but it didnt seem to work, probably an error on my part.  Your second was spot on.

Comment: @xnetdude Possibly, you didn't think to include the necessary space before the switch / between switches? I almost didn't think of it when typing my answer...